# How can i limited the distance at the Google Places API search?

Tags: google-places-api

How can I limited the distance at the Google Places API search? He found places so far from me I want to limit the distance from me to the place.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you looked at the docs for the Places API? It would be great if you could show the code you are using to query the API so it is easier for others to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var input = document.getElementById('id');
  var autocompleteOptions = {
   //types: ['(cities)'],
   componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
  };

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,autocompleteOptions);
```